# I opened gparted from the terminal and recieved this warning - Libparted-warning

Tags: gparted

```
**Libparted-warning**
Error fsyning/closing/dev/sdd:1/O-**fel on fjärrmaskin**
```

Swedish for `**error/problem on external machine**`.

Comment: Is there any more output or more details?

Comment: No, I have managed to open gparted but I've decided to install Ubuntu 16.04 over 17.10 (it is not supported much longer in any case) and not partition at this time. I have saved with Grsync on a external hard-disk. I want to be able to boot from a couple of other Linux flavors, either from partition or live disk. But I must learn more about what can be done and hopefully the error/warning will be fixed.    Graeme